# Movie where kids walk back in time ending at the primordial sea

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

I remember seeing a movie, probably in the 1980's, or even '70's.  There were some kids, at least 2, but I think a small group, say 4-5.  Somehow, as they kept walking, they kept going further and further back in time.

During a good part of the movie, they are in the time of the dinosaurs.  Eventually, at the end of the movie they end up at the primordial sea.  There is no life, nothing at all, just rocks and crashing waves.  It was kind of bleak.

I think this was a movie in the theater, but I've been Googling and Googling and I can't find anything, so it may have been a TV movie.  Sorry, the details/my memory is kind of sketchy.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Where did you see this?  What language was it in?  Did the kids talk about what was going on?

Comment: @DavidW, it would have been in US/Canada, in English.  There was conversation.  I think a lot of stuff about OMG, dinosaurs!  Watch out!  etc.

Comment: Is it possible that they weren't walking, but traveling down a river? It sounds like a little like a Czech movie made in the '50s and dubbed into English as "Journey to the Beginning of Time". It was broken into short episodes that could be incorporated into kid's TV programs (which was how I saw it, in the early-to-mid '60s).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Is it possible this is [*Journey to the Beginning of Time*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0047930/?ref_=tt_urv) (1955)?  It's a movie that involves 4 boys who go through a cave and end up travelling (in a boat mostly, not always walking) ever further back in time.  The dinosaurs and other prehistoric critters are stop-motion, composited with the live-action kids.

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_to_the_Beginning_of_Time#Plot):

> The story involves four teenage friends who take a rowboat along a "river of time" that flows into a mysterious cave and emerges on the other side onto a strange, primeval landscape. The boy actors were Josef Lukáš (Petr, the main narrator), Petr Herrmann (Toník, who also narrates in part), Zdeněk Husták (Jenda), and Vladimír Bejval (Jirka). As they make their way upstream, they realise that **they are travelling progressively farther back in time**, and face various perils as they do so (but learn much about prehistoric life in the process).

IMDb doesn't give many details but [Wikipedia notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_to_the_Beginning_of_Time#Marketing_and_retrospectives) it was translated to English in 1966 and release in the U.S.:

> In 1966, another version of the film was released in the US by William Cayton whose company had been marketing Russian animated cartoons and feature films from the 1940s and 1950s, [...] In the case of *Cesta do pravěku*, Cayton replaced the opening and closing scenes of the original with new footage of American boys who entered the film in a dream sequence whilst visiting the American Museum of Natural History in New York.

The end of the movie (last 5 minutes) shows them walking across a barren landscape to the sea; in the original Czech version they find a live trilobite in the shallows that matches the fossil they found at the start of the story.  In the U.S. version, however, the world continues to regress into vulcanism before they wake up safely back in the museum where they started.

It appears that the film may be available on YouTube:

You can also find the original Czech version:

Comment: This might well be it.  I don't remember it being Czech, but this is 'in English'...  Would this have been released at some point during that time frame?  I certainly didn't see it in the 1950's.

Comment: @Oldkid See my edits; it was dubbed into English, with an alternate beginning and ending, in 1966.

Comment: This must be it.  I'm impressed you found it so fast.  Thanks.  (It won't let me upvote :(, but I think I can accept this.)

Comment: @Oldkid I think you've collected another 10 points of reputation, so you should be able to start voting on things.  [Privileges](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges): looks like you can visit [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe) too now if you wish.  By tomorrow you should have enough rep to post comments and other stuff.

Comment: How do you find an answer to this question so fast? :P I'm a bit new here, not sure how to go about answering or asking

Comment: @DialFrost Most of the time I'm able to answer an ID question quickly, it's because I've read/seen the work in question.  Occasionally I remember the name, but mostly I just remember enough extra details to give me a better set of search terms.  And partly it's just luck.